# Given a cubic fourfold is it possible to extend an isometry on the primitive cohomology to a complete marking?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lattice-theory

Let $X$ be a (smooth) cubic fourfold and $F$ its Fano variety of lines.
It is known that $F$ is an hyperkähler fourfold. Let $(L,u)$ be an abstract lattice with a distinguished element $u$ isomorphic to $(H^4(X,\mathbb{Z}),h^2)$ , where $h^2$ is the class of a hyperplane section of $X$. We recall that a complete marking of $X$ is an isometry $H^4(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to L$ which sends $h^2$ to $u$. Moreover, let $(L',u')$ an abstract lattice, with a distinguished element $u'$, isomorphic to the pair $(H^2(F,\mathbb{Z}),g)$, where $g$ is again the class of a hyperplane section of $F$. It is known that the Abel-Jacobi map induces an isometry 
$$
H^4(X,\mathbb{Z})_{pr} \to H^2(F,\mathbb{Z})_{pr}(-1)
$$
and also we may identify the primitive part of $L'$ (i.e. the orthogonal complement of $u'$ in $L'$) with the lattice $L_0(-1)$, where $L_0$ is the orthogonal complement of $u$ in $L$. Now, let $(F,\psi)$ be a complete marking of $F$,  i.e. an isometry
$$
\psi \colon H^2(F,\mathbb{Z}) \to L' \text{ s.t. } g \mapsto u'
$$
which clearly induces an isometry
$$
\phi_0 \colon H^4(X,\mathbb{Z})_{pr} \to L_0.
$$
My questions are:

1. Is it possible to extend $\phi_0$ to a complete marking $\phi$ of $X$, i.e. an isometry $\phi \colon H^4(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to L$, with $\phi(h^2)=u$?
2. How is justified the existence of a complete marking for a cubic fourfold and for the variety of lines of a cubic fourfold?
3. If we start from a complete marking of a cubic fourfold, is it possible to "extend" this to a complete marking for its variety of lines?